# How can I create an Excel "script" that replace the value of a column with related value of a column in another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am not into **Microsoft Excel 2010** and I have the followint dout about how to face this problem.

Into a Excel sheet I have 2 tabs.

The first one (the one that will be the "source of my data") is named **Province** and contains something like this:

```
id  country_id  province_name   
1   2           Eastern Province    
2   2           Kigali city 
3   2           Northern Province   
4   2           Southern Province   
5   2           Western province
```

As you an see it contains a **province_name** column that is related to an univocal **id** column value.

Then I have another sheet that is named **Rwanda_Localization**, it contains something like this:

```
Country    City/Province        City/District
Rwanda     Eastern Province     Bugesera
Rwanda     Eastern Province     Gatsibo
Rwanda     Eastern Province     Kayonza
Rwanda     Northern Province    Burera
Rwanda     Northern Province    Gakenke
Rwanda     Southern Province    Gisagara
Rwanda     Southern Province    Huye
```

As you can see it contains a column named **City/Province** that contains the same values of the same date in the **province_name** column of the **Province** sheet.

What I need to do is to create a "script" (into Excel) that replace the value of the **City/Province** column (in the **Rwanda_Localization** sheet) with the value of the related **id** field of **Province** sheet.

For example the first row  of the **Rwanda_Localization** sheet is:

```
Rwanda     Eastern Province     Bugesera
```

and have to become:

```
Rwanda     1        Bugesera
```

because the **Eastern Province** related id is **1**

and so on for all the other rows having different values of the **City/Province** field.

How can I do something like this in Excel?

Comment: Now when you say script, is this a function you mean to implement for repeated use or a one off job? - I can give you a method to achieve your desired output in 3 steps but it's a manual process. Formulas cannot replace cell values though, only perform the lookup for you. If you expand the criteria to VBA however it's quite a simple process to create a reusable macro...

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor also a manual method will be ok for my pourpose

Answer (score 0):

This answer is set for named ranges as I don't know the target cells.

Set up another column that will house the output id and use the formula:

`INDEX(id,MATCH(B2,province_name,0))` - **B2 is the first cell of City/Province**

Now you will have the associated IDs - If you plan to delete `City/Province` afterwards be sure to copy the formulated column and paste as values to remove the formula first.

Index creates a virtual array of the target cells (id) then takes two integers that represent a row and column to return from that array. I have assumed that the ranges are the same size for this to work. Match returns an integer that represents the location of an exact match [,0)] which represents the row we wish to return as the arrays are identical sizes.

In this instance a column integer is not required as we want a result from the first column (obvious for a 1 dimensional array but yeah, it defaults to 1)